# Would the results of the Double Slit Quantum Eraser be the same using massive particles?

Tags: particle-physics, photons, mass, double-slit-experiment, quantum-eraser

I'm wondering if the double slit quantum eraser experiment would produce (or does produce, if it's already been done) the same results if massive particles were used instead of photons.

My reason for asking is that one of the confusing parts of the results, as I understand them, is that there would seem to be information "known ahead of time" or being "transmitted back in time". Could this be related to photons not experiencing time? As in (layman's logic here) maybe from the entangled pair's frame of reference, they arrive at their respective destinations at the same time...just anything that would explain the weird results. Massive particles do experience time, so I'm wondering if that would make a difference.

From cursory research (I am not an expert), it seems that there are technical reasons as to why exact replication of the experiment isn't possible with massive particles (since the entangled pair must be created after the slits). If that is true, then I am asking in theory what might be expected (and not so concerned with how the experiment would need to be set up, etc).